# Wordpress wp_query error in marketpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following function to get markerpress products in the category 'featured' and display the product images in a slideshow.

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'featured',
    'post_type' => 'product'
);
$wp_query1 = new WP_Query( $args );
                if (have_posts()) : while ( $wp_query1->have_posts() ) : $wp_query1->the_post()
```

Problem is that it does not fetch any data. I am forced to just use the below function which displays all the data.

```
$wp_query1 = new WP_Query('post_type=product');
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I set limits and also sort the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?php $args = array(
      'posts_per_page'   => 5,
      'offset'           => 0,
      'category_name'    => 'featured',
      'orderby'          => 'date',
      'order'            => 'DESC',
      'post_type'        => 'product',
      'post_status'      => 'publish'
                          );
      $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```